# Set chrony.conf file to "server" instead of "pool"

Tags: rhel, rhel7, ntpd

I'm working with RHEL 8 and the ntp package is no longer supported and it is implemented by the chronyd daemon which is provided in the chrony package. The file is set up to use public servers from the pool.ntp.org project (pool 2.rhel.pool.ntp.org iburst). Is there a way to set server instead of pool?

My chrony.conf file:

```
# Use public servers from the pool.ntp.org project.
# Please consider joining the pool (http://www.pool.ntp.org/join.html).
pool 2.rhel.pool.ntp.org iburst
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Simply comment out the pool line and add a server one with the one you want:

```
# Use public servers from the pool.ntp.org project.
# Please consider joining the pool (http://www.pool.ntp.org/join.html).

# pool 2.rhel.pool.ntp.org iburst
server 0.africa.pool.ntp.org iburst
server 0.us.pool.ntp.org
server 0.south-america.pool.ntp.org
```